# Ambiguity between method overloads with string and EventHandler parameters

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm having some difficulty with an overloaded method. My signatures look like this:

```
void Register(object source, EventHandler mapped_handler)
void Register(object source, string mapped_property)
```

I'm trying to call the first one like this:

```
Register(someObject, (s, e) => { ... });
```

Visual Studio 2008 is giving me `error CS1503: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.EventHandler' to 'string'`.

What am I missing? I'm not really sure where the problem is. I have other non-overloaded methods which I can pass `EventHandler` lambdas to without a problem.

Comment: This should work. Strip your code down as much as possible that still reproduces the problem (a class containing these two overloads with trivial definitions, and a `Main` that tries to call the `Register(object, EventHandler)` overload) and post it here and we'll see what we can do. Again, what you are trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses... turns out it was a problem in my method declarations. I had the type of the first parameter in my method signature specified wrong. I'll leave this question up for others who make silly mistakes like me.

Comment: When you have a compilation problem, strip your code as much as possible that reproduces the problem. If you can't reproduce the problem, you are making a mistake somewhere and hopefully stripping down will help find it (that's what she said).

Comment: @Jason That's exactly how I found the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

That should be absolutely fine. Short but complete example:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object o = new object();
        Register(o, (s, e) => {});
    }

    static void Register(object source, EventHandler handler)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handler");
    }

    static void Register(object source, string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text");
    }
}
```

If you could update your question with a similarly short but complete example which *doesn't* work, we may be able to help further. (My guess is that actually in the process of coming up with a short but complete example, you'll find the problem.)

The fact that your error message explicitly talks about `EventHandler` is somewhat suspicious - because the type of your argument *isn't* `EventHandler`, it's just a lambda expression which can be *converted* to `EventHandler`. Are you sure the error is on the calling line?

Comment: Could it be a difference in overload resolution between C# versions?

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Nope. This is definitely possible in .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @Anthony: I've tried it with the "Visual C# 2008" compiler as well as the more recent one. Admittedly it's SP1, but I wouldn't expect that to make a difference here. There's no conversion from a lambda expression to a string, so that method shouldn't be part of the candidate set.

Comment: @Jason and Jon, yes, just tested that hypothesis as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
Register(someObject, new EventHandler((s,e)=>{...}));
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation why?

Comment: Jason is right - you shouldn't need to do this. There's more to the question than what we've been told, I suspect.

Comment: Ahh, I wonder if you have something like this?

private void Register(Object o, EventHandler h) { ... }
private void Register(Object o, EventHandler<EventArgs> h) { ... }

In that case, the inference would be ambiguous...

Comment: @Chris Shain: No, that is not the case at all. There is some piece of information that we are not being provided that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Chris: It can tell that it can't convert from a lambda expression to a string, which isn't a delegate type... see my answer which shows this code compiling with no problems.

Comment: @Chris: In that case that would be a completely different set of signatures from the ones given. It also wouldn't explain why "string" is mentioned in the error message.